# How to replace every existing values of a column with formula?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

My sheet already has data. Unfortunately, later I realized that all the values in column E should be validated and changed as necessary by calling my own user-defined function and passing the values as the function parameter. For example, say I have the following data in column E:

```
E1: "This is a text in (E1)"
E2: "This is a text in (E2)"
...
E7000: "This is a text in (E7000)"
```

Now, I want every value in column E to be changed by a formula like this:

```
E1: = RemoveBrackets("This is a text in (E1)")
E2: = RemoveBrackets("This is a text in (E2)")
...
E7000: = RemoveBrackets("This is a text in (E7000)")
```

Supposing Excel supports Regex, my problem can be solved easily. but unfortunately Excel doesn't. Could someone propose possible solutions to my problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Insert a new column "F"

2) Copy column E into F

3) Write in E1

```
 =RemoveBrackets(F1)
```

4) Drag the E1 value through E7000

5) Hide column F.

### Edit 1

You can do it with several passes of the Find/Replace feature:

Select the Column E before each PASS.

**PASS 1**

```
Find:              <"This is a text in>
Replace with:      <RemoveBrackets("This is a text in>
```

**PASS 2**

```
Find:              <)">
Replace with:      <)")>
```

**PASS 3**

```
Find:              <RemoveBrackets(>
Replace with:      <=RemoveBrackets(>
```

### Edit 2

VB Regex substitute string function can be used from Excel.
You may dowload a toolpack such as [Morefunc](http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/index.htm) which supports a REGEX.SUBSTITUTE udf, or you could do your own udf using [THIS](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T003303_Wildcards_in_Replace_With_Text.html) as guideline.

I am posting here the code from the second reference, just for link independence:

```
Public Function SearchNReplace1(Pattern1 As String, _
  Pattern2 As String, Replacestring As String, _
  TestString As String)
    Dim reg As New RegExp
    reg.IgnoreCase = True
    reg.MultiLine = False
    reg.Pattern = Pattern1
    If reg.Test(TestString) Then
        reg.Pattern = Pattern2
        SearchNReplace1 = reg.Replace(TestString, ReplaceString)
    Else
        SearchNReplace1 = TestString
   End If
End Function
```

Please read the full article, as you should turn on the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 option in Excel first.

HTH

Comment: I have already thought about this, I just hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks very much @belisarius, your *edit 1* is cunning, I like that, how can I didn't think about it; and your *edit 2*, I'm not aware of it, thanks for the new knowledge. :-) Well, about your first answer, the reason for my rejection is I've already thought about that, and I consider such a solution should exists in every newbies' mind (please don't be offended), I appreciate your 2nd and 3rd answers though. :-)

Comment: @Vantomex. Glad to help. Regarding your comment about the first answer ... many, many times happens that a seasoned programmer overlooks the evident, just because he/she is trapped in the lets-do-it-this-way web.

Comment: I think you're right. OK, I'll try to provide background details as needed next time. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to belisarius' method, but doesn't leave a trace:

1. Insert column F
2. Insert into F1 the value `=RemoveBrackets(F1)`
3. Copy down through F7000.
4. Copy column F
5. Right click cell E1, Paste Special, choose "Values".
6. Delete column F

Comment: your solution is tricky too, I accept this as an accepted answer too just like @belisarius' answer. Unfortunately, the rule here has restricted me to accept more than one answer, and I don't have rights to Vote Up yet, sorry. Thanks very much @Jon. :-)